# PyQt5 - Signal : pyqtSignal no method connect

Tags: python-3.x, signals, pyqt5

following example in this doc found on [sourceforge](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSlot)
I faced an error.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

 def setSignal():        
     signal = pyqtSignal()
     signal.connect(self.myAction)

 @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
 def myAction():
     print("signal triggered")
```

results in

```
AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs you linked, a signal needs to be defined on class level:

```
class Foo(QObject):

    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def connectSignal():        
        self.signal.connect(self.myAction)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def myAction():
        print("signal triggered")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unforyunately defining signal as class member (in python3 in the \__init\__ function) doesn't change anything, same error raised. Moreover as the signal type is known in the error message, I don't think this is the issue

Comment: but defining signal as you mentionned does work. I thought it was similar declaration. Actually it isn't,  thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's mandatory to define them on class level, you can't do it in `__init__`. One defines a class variable (like a method is too), the other a instance variable. Signals need to be class variables.